While trying to restart a dev container in Visual Studio Code I am getting the following message in terminal
Command failed: node /root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.375.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js read-configuration --workspace-folder /workspaces/hvac --id-label vsc.devcontainer.volume.name=hvac --id-label vsc.devcontainer.volume.folder=hvac --log-level debug --log-format json --mount-workspace-git-root
This is a recurring problem with every dev container i create . Please help
I have tried foloign  steps Verify Dev Containers Extension:
Ensure you have the latest version of the Dev Containers extension installed in VS Code.
Check Dev Containers CLI Installation:
Make sure the Dev Containers CLI is properly installed and accessible.
Permissions:
Ensure you have the necessary permissions to access the workspace folder and the associated volumes.
Log Details:
Review the debug logs for more specific error details. Since the command includes --log-level debug and --log-format json, there should be more detailed logs available.
Configuration File:
Verify the configuration file (e.g., devcontainer.json) in your workspace for any syntax errors or misconfigurations.
Volumes:
Check the Docker volumes specified in the command to ensure they exist and are correctly mounted.

You need to check the workspace folder path (in your case /workspaces/hvac). or you can try to rebuild Dev Containers by right-clicking the Container name in the VS Code status bar and select "Rebuild Container".

Usually, you need to check the workspace folder path (in your case /workspaces/hvac). or you can try to rebuild Dev Containers by right-clicking the Container name in the VS Code status bar and select "Rebuild Container".
